# Redirect cout from C++ dll to a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, console

I'm trying to display the console output (cout) of a method in a dll to a textbox in C# program. Every time I call the method, the console output will be displayed in the Output Pane of Visual Studio. Is there a way to redirect the content of the Output Pane to the textbox?

The dll was written by someone else in C++ and I have no control in changing it.
The dll is wrapped using SWIG so that it can be called by my C# code.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://pastebin.com/f3eda7c8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After following the link suggested by David, I decided to write a solution to your problem which is more specific to your case. This version allows you to receive the stdout in your GUI via a `BackgroundWorker` `PropertyChangedEventHandler` call back.

Here's the code for the ConsoleRedirector:

```
public class ConsoleRedirector : IDisposable
{
    private static ConsoleRedirector _instance;

    public static void attach(ProgressChangedEventHandler handler, bool forceConsoleRedirection)
    {
        Debug.Assert(null == _instance);
        _instance = new ConsoleRedirector(handler, forceConsoleRedirection);

    }

    public static void detatch()
    {
        _instance.Dispose();
        _instance = null;
    }

    public static bool isAttached
    {
        get
        {
            return null != _instance;
        }
    }

    private static void ResetConsoleOutStream()
    {
        //Force console to recreate its output stream the next time Write/WriteLine is called
        typeof(Console).GetField("_out", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(null, null);
    }

    private const int PERIOD = 500;
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    private volatile bool _isDisposed;
    private BackgroundWorker _worker;
    private readonly IntPtr _stdout;
    private readonly Mutex _sync;
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly char[] _buffer;
    private readonly AnonymousPipeServerStream _outServer;
    private readonly TextReader _outClient;
    private readonly bool _forceConsoleRedirection;

    private StreamWriter _consoleStandardOut;

    private ConsoleRedirector(ProgressChangedEventHandler handler, bool forceConsoleRedirection)
    {
        bool ret;
        _forceConsoleRedirection = forceConsoleRedirection;

        if (!_forceConsoleRedirection)
        {
            //Make sure Console._out is initialized before we redirect stdout, so the redirection won't affect it
            TextWriter temp = Console.Out;
        }

        AnonymousPipeClientStream client;

        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.ProgressChanged += handler;
        _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        _stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        _sync = new Mutex();
        _buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];

        _outServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out);
        client = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, _outServer.ClientSafePipeHandle);
        Debug.Assert(_outServer.IsConnected);
        _outClient = new StreamReader(client, Encoding.Default);
        ret = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _outServer.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
        Debug.Assert(ret);

        if (_forceConsoleRedirection)
        {
            ResetConsoleOutStream(); //calls to Console.Write/WriteLine will now get made against the redirected stream
        }

        _worker.RunWorkerAsync(_outClient);

        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(flush, null, PERIOD, PERIOD);

    }

    void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        TextReader client = (TextReader)e.Argument;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = client.Read(_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                if (read > 0)
                    worker.ReportProgress(0, new string(_buffer, 0, read));
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // Pipe was closed... terminate

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private void flush(object state)
    {
        _outServer.Flush();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    ~ConsoleRedirector()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            lock (_sync)
            {
                if (!_isDisposed)
                {
                    _isDisposed = true;
                    _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                    _timer.Dispose();
                    flush(null);

                    try { SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, _stdout);}
                    catch (Exception) { }
                    _outClient.Dispose();
                    _outServer.Dispose();

                    if (_forceConsoleRedirection)
                    {
                        ResetConsoleOutStream(); //Calls to Console.Write/WriteLine will now get redirected to the original stdout stream
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetStdHandle(int nStdHandle, IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
}
```

Here's a link to a complete sample form which demonstrates how to use it: [ConsoleRedirector Example Form](http://pastebin.com/UubBhyqJ)

Comment: I've been using this brilliant code in my app, worked great in Windows 7!  When I upgraded to Windows 10 this no longer works.  Do you have any idea what about Windows 10 might have broken the above code?

Comment: First, I would do a debug build of your app and check that the debug.assert statements pass.  Then I would step through slowly and see which part appears to not work as intended - is it  failing on the _client.read in the background worker's method or is client null or closed coming in?  I'm not aware of changes in Windows 10 that would effect this.

Comment: @Erikest I tested it and when I click "attach" all msgs except output from dll are printed to textbox :( dll print is still in console. Do you also have this problem?